# Mongo DB aggregate update array field if empty else return existing value

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a document with below data

```
[
  {
    "name": "demo",
    "data": [
      {
        "isvalid": true,
        "mdata": [
          {
            "name": "hello"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "isvalid": false,
        "mdata": []
      },
      {
        "isvalid": true,
        "mdata": [
          {
            "name": "hello"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    
  }
]
```

Doing aggregate operation with below query based on data.isvalid field, also used set operation to retrieve only matching fields in the response instead of getting entire array data.
But I have another requirement where I need to update the entire array field(mdata) to "[{}]" when its empty i.e []. Used $addfields option to achieve this and is working fine as expected with query below, but when the array field is not empty its appending the value twice instead of keeping the same value. Not sure why its appending instead of updating/keeping the same value.

Mongo Playground Ref: https://mongoplayground.net/p/h7oxPKIGs2n

working case:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "data.isvalid": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$data",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this.isvalid",
              false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "data.mdata": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$lte": [
              {
                "$size": "$data.mdata"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "then": [
            {}
          ],
          "else": "$data.mdata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

fail case:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "data.isvalid": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$data",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this.isvalid",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "data.mdata": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$lte": [
              {
                "$size": "$data.mdata"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "then": [
            {}
          ],
          "else": "$data.mdata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Since you're working with nested arrays, you may need to `$map` over the outer one (`data`) during that last agg stage

Comment: what is your desired output you want, mention that.